# NUnit-2 | Get TestResult.xml report in runtime

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-console

I have a single Test.dll which have thousands of test case inside it. I am using the NUnit 2.x framework.
When running NUnit test by NUnit-console, I must wait several hours and just get the test report after it finished the whole test suit.

May I get the TestResult.xml more frequently. Now, I cannot catch up the test progress (how many passed, failed, in running...)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The NUnit V2 console runner provides an XML result output, which it creates at the end of the test run. Since it's legacy software, no longer under active development, that's not likely to change.

However, the runner does provide the `labels` option, which causes the name of each test to be written to the console at the time it starts.

For a more detailed output while the test runs, you may run a debug build of your tests under a debugger. In that case, the console runner writes information about any test failures to the trace output.